# Literal assumption during arithmetic operation in Java

Tags: java, operators, literals

How does one explain the syntax error for the following code:

long x = 10;
int y = 2 * x;

I was taught literals are interpreted as an int data type and must include a postfix "L" to become a long data type. Why was x successfully assigned as a long data type despite without having the `L` suffix?

Comment: You can _always_ assign an `int` to a `long`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! So for the example above, would it be right to assume x is technically treated as a long data type but with int's capacity of 4 bytes?

Comment: No. The integer `10` is widened to a `long`. You then tried to assign the `long` result of multiplying a `long` by 2 into an `int`, and got a compilation error.

Comment: But if you want `x` to be `long` why are you computing with it and then trying to store the result in an `int`? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JeffreyHu you can have a look inside the compiled class to see what's happening with `javap -verbose Classname`

[Here's the output](https://gist.github.com/robobario/5c442592a3fd72a8bf24315389e4d91b) I see for `long x = 10` on jdk8. See how the compiled class has a long constant and manipulates it with ldc2_w and lstore.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to: `long x = 10; int y = (int) (2 * x);` and it should work.

You have to cast `long` types to `int` because `long` types are `64 bit` wide whereas `int` types are `32 bit` wide. You can think of a `long` type as a superset of an `int` type.

Thus, this will be totally legal: `int x = 10; long y = 2 * x;` without casting `long` to `int`. In fact, casting, in this case, will be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Best to specify what the syntax error was.  I believe what you are running into is that you cannot multiply an int (2) by a long (x) and store it in an int.  Java seems smart enough that long x = 10 ; .... is interpreted fine as you can store an int into a long.

Best practice would be to not assign a product of a `long` and an `int` into an `int`.  If you must do that, however, and you are certain that the `long` is not too long (lots of assumptions there) ... you can always do:

```
 long x = 10 ;
 int y = 2 * (int)x ;
```

By casting the long to an int ... Java lets you do it ... but again, this is not recommended.